# I can't deserialize JSON object like I want

Tags: c#, json

I have a web response like this:

```
[{
  "st1": [
    "folio1",
    "folio2"
  ],
  "st2": [
    "folio1"
  ]
}]
```

This is my code to call my web server:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri+"server/getSTFolios/");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
 var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var Item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ST>>(content);
 return Item;
}
```

This is ST class, to deserialize my response

```
public class ST
    {
        private string v;

        public ST(string v)
        {
            this.v = v;
        }

        public string st { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public int pk { get; set; }
        public List<Folio> folios { get; set; } 
        public override string ToString()
        {
           return "ST: " + st;
        }
    }
```

But I can't obtain my object, I can't deserialize.
I obtaint this when I try print `Item.ToString()`

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test2.ST]
```

This is my debugger.
[image: Debug my function]
Thanks

Comment: That's by design; you didn't override `ToString()`.  You don't actually have a problem.

Comment: @SLaks but I try print without `ToString()` is same problem `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test2.ST]`

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get if you "print" your object?

Comment: That still calls `ToString()`.  If you want to print the values, you'll need to write code that does that.

Comment: @JoshPart I expect to get my object, I need see that all okay. (That this correct built)

Comment: @fabulias: .Net will not convert your object to a string in a useful way; you need to do that yourself.

Comment: @fabulias that's the part you don't really understand. **you are** getting your object; your object is a `List<st>`; this is, a collection of  `st`. Your object is **not** a string and thus trying to print it like one only gives you the  name of the type of our object. You need to do something like `Item[0].st`, `Item[0].location` or even `Item[0].folios[0].ToString()` to obtain one of the values of your response.

Comment: @JoshPart Okay, but I can't see a variables correctly assigned.

Comment: I don't think your class definition is right, For that exact JSON response, json2csharp.com suggests `public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> st1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> st2 { get; set; }
}` - the JSON you post **doesn't have the properties sk, location, pk etc** - where do you expect them to come from?

Comment: @stuartd But st1 and st2 are dynamic, could are st2000. Please help, I'm very confused

Comment: Mayor my response web could distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess this is because your trying to deserialize your JSON object with

```
var Item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ST>>(content);
```

But the response you're receiving isn't in the same class format as `ST`.

You're trying to convert an object that looks like

```
{
    "st1": ["folio1","folio2"],
    "st2": ["folio1"]
}
```

to this

```
public class ST
{
    public string st { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public int pk { get; set; }
    public List<Folio> folios { get; set; } 
}
```

They share no properties or anything at all. That's why, when debugging and hovering over `Item`, you do see a single object in that list, but all the values are null. The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` tried to convert your response into the format of `ST` but found no matching properties, and simply created an empty `ST`.

If you were to receive a response with more than one object like

```
[{
    "st1": ["folio1","folio2"],
    "st2": ["folio1"]
},
{
    "st1": ["folio1","folio2"],
    "st2": ["folio1"]
}]
```

When hovering over `Item`, you'll have 2 objects full of null values.

## Edit

You need to make your server respond with objects that look like the `ST` class. For example, if you had a response that looked something like this, I assume it would work:

```
[{
    "st": "some string",
    "location": "some string",
    "note": "some string",
    "pk": 123,
    "folios" : 
    [{ 
        "pk": 123,
        "number": "some string" 
     },
     { 
        "pk": 123,
        "number": "some string" 
     }]
}]
```

Comment: But I could fix this error, I am know that my properties are confused But I dont know what to do.

Comment: You either need to re-write your `ST` class to match your response types, or make the response you receive to follow the format of the `ST` class.

Comment: but... what is the correctly format to send data from my server?, I feel missing the 'st' and 'folio' tag but with that would it suffice? How would it be? Thank you

Comment: Like this? `[
  {
    "st": "st1",
    "folios":["folio1", "folio2"]
  },
  {
   "st": "st2",
   "folios":["folio1", "folio8"]
  },
  {
   "st": "st3",
   "folios":["folio1", "folio20"]
  }
]`

Comment: Hey bro, I can convert my data to that, but I have the same problem with "folio", the console return me this error `Error converting value "folio1" to type 'test2.Folio'. Path '[0].folios[0]', line 1, position 21. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to test2.Folio.`, this is example to response `[
  {
    "folios": [
      "folio1",
      "folio2"
    ],
    "st": "st1"
  },
  {
    "folios": [
      "folio2"
    ],
    "st": "st2"
  }
]`

Comment: `Could not cast or convert from System.String to test2.Folio.` It's the same issue. Make sure your responses, when it returns `Folio` objects, that they're in the same format. You can't return `{ "folios": [ "folio2" ], "st": "st2" }` because you're trying to return a string `"folio2"` where it should return a `Folio` object.

Comment: Like this... `{ "folios": [ {"folio2"}, {"folio10"} ], "st": "st2" }` ????

Comment: I don't know what your `Folio` objects look like.

Comment: `public class Folio
 {
  public Folio(string number)
  {
   this.number = number;
  }
  public int pk { get; set; }
  public string number { get; set; }
 }`

Comment: And this JSON object???  `[
  {
    "folios": [
      {
        "number": [
          "folio1",
          "folio2"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "st": "st1"
  },
  {
    "folios": [
      {
        "number": [
          "folio2"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "st": "st2"
  }
]`